# Obtaining the average of one field with comma delimited values (InfoPath)

Tags: function, math, xpath, infopath

I have a field where the user enters multiple values each separated by a comma eg "1.8, 2, 3".

I want to find the average of those values. Is there a way to utilise avg() to accommodate for stripping the comma and producing the mean?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't do that with the built in InfoPath functions (there is no traditional split method for strings).

If you are willing to tackle it - using managed code behind the form will very easily solve your problem (only about 4 lines of code). Basic math and string manipulation should not impose any security restrictions on the form. However you will have to setup for code behind which is easy but can seem like somewhat of a hassle the first time you try it. There are good MSDN articles on how to go about that.

Alternatively, if you can change your data entry from comma separated to a repeating table you can use the built in avg() function.

Comment: ok, thanks for the response. I think I'll just code it behind the form as I already have two repeating tables and could easily run a few pages down if I introduce another.